# Button is not selectable on tvOS using own ButtonStyle in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, tvos

After replacing a standard button style with a custom one, the button isn't selectable anymore on tvOS (it works as expected on iOS). Is there a special modifier in PlainButtonStyle() that I'm missing? Or is it a bug in SwiftUI?

Here's the snipped that works:

```
Button(
    action: { },
    label: { Text("Start") }
).buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
```

and here's the one that doesn't:

```
Button(
    action: { },
    label: { Text("Start") }
).buttonStyle(RoundedButtonStyle())
```

where RoundedButtonStyle() is defined as:

```
struct RoundedButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .padding(6)
            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            .background(Color.blue)
            .cornerRadius(100)
    }
}
```

Comment: Buttons in tvOS seem to be very fragile, you might consider trying a ViewModifier instead, but avoid setting any kind of shadow or shape mask on the button or any containing views as that will break the buttons as well.

Comment: You're right, I ended up using a view modifier instead of the button style. This is working as expected.

Answer (score 2):

If you create your own style you have to handle focus manual. Of course there are different ways how you could do this.

```
struct RoundedButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {

    let focused: Bool
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration
            .label
            .padding(6)
            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            .background(Color.blue)
            .cornerRadius(100)
            .shadow(color: .black, radius: self.focused ? 20 : 0, x: 0, y: 0) //  0

    }
}
```

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var buttonFocus: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello World")

            Button(
                action: { },
                label: { Text("Start") }
            ).buttonStyle(RoundedButtonStyle(focused: buttonFocus))
                .focusable(true) { (value) in
                    self.buttonFocus = value
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I was missing the modifier ".focusable(true)". It's now possible to focus the button, but unfortunately, the action of the button is never triggered. Any idea what the reason is?

Comment: anyone got a solution for this? Same problem

Answer (score 2):

I have done it in this way and it's working fine, what you need to do is just handling the focused state.

```
struct AppButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
  
  let color: Color = .clear

  func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
    return AppButton(configuration: configuration, color: color)
  }
  
  
  struct AppButton: View {
    @State var focused: Bool = false

    let configuration: ButtonStyle.Configuration
    let color: Color
    
    var body: some View {
      configuration.label
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20).fill(color))
        .compositingGroup()
        .shadow(color: .black, radius: 5)
        .scaleEffect(focused ? 1.1 : 1.0)
        .padding()
        .focusable(true) { focused in
          withAnimation {
            self.focused = focused
          }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

When the button is getting focused I'm just scaling it and you can do something else as you wish with the same idea, so let's say you wan't to change the background color:

```
.background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20).fill(focused ? .red : .white))
```

To use:

```
struct SomeView: View {
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      NavigationLink(
        destination: Text("Destination")) {
        Text("Hi")
      }
      .buttonStyle(AppButtonStyle())
      .padding()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! The `focusable(_:)` func is deprecated now, so I'm using the environment var instead - `@Environment(\.isFocused) var isFocused: Bool`. Everything else is working really great :)