# How to react on press of styled button in tvOS with SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, tvos

If you style a Button element in tvOS, you have to manage focus manually as described in this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58179225/10826194

Unfortunately, the action attached to the button is never called. Also, there is no TapGesture on tvOS.
How can I attach an action to a styled tvOS button?

Comment: `ButtonStyleConfiguration.isPressed` is not triggered (as well as `PrimitiveButtonStyleConfiguration.trigger`), so it seems like custom button styles are not supported at all for tvOS. You should submit feedback to Apple.

Comment: A number of us have submitted this matter to Apple's Feedback Assistant and haven't heard back yet. Thanks for calling it out here as well.